# arranging columns using dplyr::select without hardcoding

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am loading a csv file. I am trying to arrange the columns based on the of string of column names I have. I have about 50 columns. I am curious as to how do I arrange the columns using

```
  dplyr::select
```

I see the argument it takes are the column names directly, without referring it as a string. So may have to hardcode the name. This is straight forward to do if I refer the dataframe (and avoiding hard code) using

```
 [
```

Here is an example

```
table = data.frame(cnty=c(1,2,3), empcnt1=c(200,300,400), 
wage1=c(40,50,60),empcnt2=c(200,300,400),
wage2=c(40,50,60),empcnt3=c(200,300,400), wage3=c(40,50,60))

col.string <- c("empcnt1","wage1","empcnt2","wage2","empcnt3","wage3","cnty")
table1 <- table[col.string]
```

Using

```
dplyr::select
table2 <- select(table,empcnt1,wage1,empdiff,empcnt2,wage2,empcnt3,wage3,cnty)
table2 <- select(table,empcnt1:wage3,cnty)
```

Note I am not able to leverage the fact I have

```
col.string
```

I have about 50 columns, so trying to avoid hard coding when using dplyr:select.

Comment: I'm not clear what your question is, actually. Are you looking for how to use a character vector in `select`? If so, you might be looking for something like `table %>% select_(.dots = col.string)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you want to use `select_` along with the `.dots` argument:

```
> table %>% select_(.dots = col.string)
  empcnt1 wage1 empcnt2 wage2 empcnt3 wage3 cnty
1     200    40     200    40     200    40    1
2     300    50     300    50     300    50    2
3     400    60     400    60     400    60    3
```

Comment: Thank you - Yes, that is what I was looking for. Passing a string argument in select - and select_ with .dots seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @rajvijay, OK cool. The `.dots` thing can be hard to miss at first (as can the functions ending with underscores).